# Resize video when scaling/minimizing YoutubePlayerView in android

Tags: android, youtube, android-videoview, viewgroup

I have followed the tutorial at the link below to create YouTube like functionality where the YouTube player view can be minimized to the lower right hand corner of the screen.

http://flavienlaurent.com/blog/2013/08/28/each-navigation-drawer-hides-a-viewdraghelper/

However, the video currently does not scale to the size of the reduced window and retains the original size.

How can I update the YoutubePlayerView to change the size of the video to change with the scaling?

view.xml:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.example.views.YoutubeVideoView
        android:id="@+id/youtubeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible" >

        <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
            android:id="@+id/youtube_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/viewDesc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#FF00FF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:tag="desc"
            android:text="Loreum Loreum"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="35sp" />
    </com.example.views.YoutubeVideoView>
</FrameLayout>
```

DragHelperCallback which is included in my YoutubeVideoView class, which extends ViewGroup:

```
private class DragHelperCallback extends ViewDragHelper.Callback {

    @Override
    public boolean tryCaptureView(View child, int pointerId) {
        return child == mVideoView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewPositionChanged(View changedView, int left, int top,
            int dx, int dy) {
        mTop = top;

        mDragOffset = (float) top / mDragRange;

        mVideoView.setPivotX(mVideoView.getWidth());
        mVideoView.setPivotY(mVideoView.getHeight());
        mVideoView.setScaleX(1 - mDragOffset / 2);
        mVideoView.setScaleY(1 - mDragOffset / 2);
        mDescView.setAlpha(1 - mDragOffset);

        requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewReleased(View releasedChild, float xvel, float yvel) {
        int top = getPaddingTop();
        if (yvel > 0 || (yvel == 0 && mDragOffset > 0.5f)) {
            top += mDragRange;
        }
        mDragHelper.settleCapturedViewAt(releasedChild.getLeft(), top);
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewVerticalDragRange(View child) {
        return mDragRange;
    }

    @Override
    public int clampViewPositionVertical(View child, int top, int dy) {
        final int topBound = getPaddingTop();
        final int bottomBound = getHeight() - mVideoView.getHeight()
                - mVideoView.getPaddingBottom();

        final int newTop = Math.min(Math.max(top, topBound), bottomBound);
        return newTop;
    }

}
```

overridden onLayout method in my YoutubeVideoView class, which extends ViewGroup

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    mDragRange = getHeight() - mVideoView.getHeight();

    mVideoView.layout(0, mTop, r, mTop + mVideoView.getMeasuredHeight());

    mDescView
            .layout(0, mTop + mVideoView.getMeasuredHeight(), r, mTop + b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I just had a similar issue using DraggablePanel. DraggablePanel is based off of ViewDragHelper. If you adjust the height and width layout params for the YouTubePlayerView, the playing video adjust as well. I don't know why scaling the view doesn't adjust the playing video. I talk about my solution more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26830310/resize-scaling-down-a-youtubeplayerfragment-while-video-is-playing). The [ResizeTransformer](https://github.com/pedrovgs/DraggablePanel/blob/develop/draggablepanel/src/main/java/com/github/pedrovgs/transformer/ResizeTransformer.java) in the DraggablePanel library will also help you alot.