# Floating video player using Youtube Android Player API

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I want to create a video player which plays Youtube video. I used `YouTubePlayerView`. It play the Youtube video. but i want the floating video player same as Youtube has.

Comment: Try to make use of the [DraggablePanel library](https://github.com/pedrovgs/DraggablePanel) in Github. Draggable Panel is an Android library created to build a draggable user interface similar to the new YouTube draggable video component based on Fragments or Views. Check this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26830310/resize-scaling-down-a-youtubeplayerfragment-while-video-is-playing) for additional insight.

Comment: Thanks, for help. It is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to make use of the [DraggablePanel library](https://github.com/pedrovgs/DraggablePanel) in Github. Draggable Panel is an Android library created to build a draggable user interface similar to the new YouTube draggable video component based on Fragments or Views. Check this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26830310/resize-scaling-down-a-youtubeplayerfragment-while-video-is-playing) for additional insight.